# How to handle page crashed exception in node.js puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, puppeteer

Occasionally, when I run my puppeteer script, I’ll get a “page crashed” error. It’s most likely not a software error, but something to do with the proxy IPs I’m using/webpages I’m scraping. So all I’m really looking to do is just catch the error, close the current page, and open up a new page.

However, my try catch block doesn’t seem to be working. My code is structured like this:

```
try {
   //puppeteer code
}
catch(e) {
   console.log(‘caught error ‘ + e);
}
```

But when the page crashed error happens, I see “unhandled promise rejection error” instead of my console.log message. What’s going on here?

Comment: 1) you can use `e.message` to only print the message. 2) please provide more detailed code, do you have any code outside of try/catch block? 3) have you tried calling it on `error` event? e.g. `page.on('error', msg => throw msg)`

Comment: There’s no code outside of the try-catch block. I didn’t know that page.on(‘error’) was a thing...where exactly would I put that code?

Comment: put it somewhere after creating `newPage()` and before `goto()`

Comment: maybe catch errors where error might happen like `await page.goto('example.com').catch(function (error) {     throw new Error('this error happend');   });`

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3709):

```js
page.on('error', msg => {
  console.error(...);
  throw msg ;
});
```

And this is also advised to globally catch all uncaught errors in your code:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  console.error(...);
  throw error;
});
```